# Catching explicit exceptions from a hierarchy

Tags: java, exception

I have a set of exceptions under a base exception called `ServiceException`. These exception include explicit reasons for service failure - `BadRequestException`, `ServiceUnreachableException` to indicate behavior my classes can't fix themselves.

This hierarchy looks a little something like so:

```
public class ServiceException extends Exception {
    public ServiceException() { super(); }

    public ServiceException(String message) { super(message); }

    public ServiceException(String message, Throwable cause) { super(message, cause); }

    public ServiceException(Throwable cause) { super(cause); }
}
```

and an example of one of the sub-types:

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;

@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ServiceUnreachableException extends ServiceException {
    private final String message;
    private final Throwable cause;
}
```

When I go to use this I would like to have the following structure:

```
public void doProcess() throws ServiceException {
   ...
}

public void processor() {

  try {
    doProcess()
  } catch (BadRequestException e) {
    // Handle specific exception
  } catch (ServiceUnreachableException e) {
    // etc
  } catch (InvalidApiKeyException e) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

this enables me to cleanly use the catch blocks to catch the various exceptions. It seems though that Java can't infer that the exceptions are thrown by the `doProcess` method explicitly via `throws ServiceException`.

This would lead me to believe I would need to do one of the following:

```
public void doProcess() throws BadRequestException, ServiceUnreachableException, InvalidApiKeyException {
   ...
}

public void processor() {

  try {
    doProcess();
  } catch (BadRequestException e) {
    // Handle specific exception
  } catch (ServiceUnreachableException e) {
    // etc
  } catch (InvalidApiKeyException e) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

or

```
public void doProcess() throws ServiceException {
   ...
}

public void processor() {

  try {
    doProcess();
  } catch (ServiceException e)  {
     if(e instanceof BadRequestException) {
       // cast and do stuff
     } else if(e instanceof ServiceUnreachableException) {
       // cast and do stuff
     } else if(e instanceof InvalidApiKeyException) {
        //cast and do stuff
     }
  }
}
```

Which seems more messy in exchange for the cleaner `doProcess` method definition.

Which is more correct here? They both work but I feel like the `catch` version is how you're supposed to use exceptions, and the other is a mess because `doProcess` decided to save a few lines by not explicitly enumerating all exceptions it throws.

Thank you!

Comment: I think in your second alternative you meant to write `throws ServiceException`.

Comment: @RobinGreen nice catch thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It seems though that Java can't infer that the exceptions are thrown
>   by the `doProcess` method explicitly via `throws ServiceException`.

No, it can't, because it has no way to be confident that it knows about all the subclasses of `ServiceException` that exist now or may exist in the future.

> Which is more correct here?

It's not a question of *correctness*.  Both approaches can get the job done.  But I consider it poor style to catch a general exception and then use conditional expressions to select behavior for specific subtypes.  You ought to use `catch` blocks to associate handlers with specific exceptions.

But I think you have asked the wrong question.  Note well that there is a third alternative that is at least as good as the first:

```
public void doProcess() throws ServiceException {
   ...
}

public void processor() {
  try {
    doProcess();
  } catch (BadRequestException e) {
    // Handle specific exception
  } catch (ServiceUnreachableException e) {
    // etc
  } catch (InvalidApiKeyException e) {
    // ...
  } catch (ServiceException e) {
    // fallback for any other flavor of ServiceException
    // ...
  }
}
```

Of course, that supposes that you want to avoid `processor()` declaring any checked exceptions; else you could have it, too, throw `ServiceException` instead of providing a generic catch block for it.

Thus, the question you should be asking is not how to catch but what to throw.  That's a design consideration that we haven't enough information to opine about.

Comment: Thank you. Yes it was even confusing for me to write. I appreciate the time you took writing this up.